# Using an array of objects as property inside of Backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Just starting out with Backbone so sorry if this is a basic question.

I have a Model which has an array of objects as a property, something like this.

```
var Ship = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        coordinates: []
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.on('change:coordinates', this.onChange);  
    },
    onChange: function () {
        console.log('CHANGED!!');  
    },
});

var ship = new Ship();

ship.set('coordinates', [{xAxis:1, yAxis:1}, {xAxis:1, yAxis:2}]);

var targetHitCoordinates = _.findWhere(ship.get('coordinates'), {xAxis:1, yAxis:1});

targetHitCoordinates.isHit = true;

console.log(ship);
```

When i set isHit to true the change event doesn't fire even though the property is added to the coordinates object inside of the array.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is change triggered with the first coordinate .set ?

Comment: Yeah it is but not when isHit is changed

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are not using the .set method.

Something like that should work:

```
var targetHitCoordinates = _.findWhere(ship.get('coordinates'), {xAxis:1, yAxis:1});

targetHitCoordinates.isHit = true;

ship.set('coordinates', [targetHitCoordinates]);
```

Let me know if it works

I'm not sure to understand the way you are managing you model property but anyway you need to use .set()

So you could juste use

```
ship.set({ hit:true });
```

and define another listener for the hit event.

Comment: Hi François. I think that will fire the change event but it will also over write the entire array and not just update the property.

Comment: Just btw, the standard way to use set now is with object, key-value pairs like, ship.set({coordinates: [targetHitCoordinates]});